# «Хочу» и «хотел бы»

Tags: смысл

«Хочу» и «хотел бы» — это одно и то же? Как сказать правильно?

Comment: Согласен, Сергей! Да, к сожалению формой с "бы" последнее время злоупотребляют. Думаю, что с памятью у Вас всё в порядке.

Answer (score 3):

Это может быть и одним и тем же, и разным.

*В первом случае* это просто более **вежливая форма:**

> Я бы хотел попробовать вот этого салата.

Вежливость может быть как искренней — честная боязнь побеспокоить человека, готовность к отказу, так и наигранной, желанием подлизаться к кому-то.

Если отношения очень хорошие, ты уверен в готовности другого тебе помочь и момент не отличается деликатностью, можно сказать просто *"я хочу",* например:

> Я хочу тебя кое о чём попросить.

Если произносить это не резким тоном, а по-доброму, друг ни за что тебя не упрекнёт в невежливости.

*Во втором случае* это может быть **сослагательным наклонением с нереальным условием:**

> Я хотел бы слетать на Луну.

Он не может на неё слетать (нужно быть космонавтом или иметь огромные деньги), но хотел бы, если бы мог.

На всякий случай оговорюсь, что то, что я назвал вежливой формой, тоже относится к сослагательному наклонению.